# Windows 10 при запуске открыто меню пуск, как это изменить?

Tags: windows-10

Можно ли как-то отключить авто-открытие меню пуск в Windows 10 при запуске?

Answer (score 1):

1. Правый клик по свободной области панели задач. Откроется контекстное меню, выберите <kbd>Properties</kbd>.
2. В открывшемся окне выберите третью вкладку <kbd>Start Menu</kbd>
3. На вкладке есть верхний чекбокс «use the Start menu instead of the Start screen». Уберите галочку, нажмите <kbd>OK</kbd> внизу окна.
4. Перелогиньтесь. Теперь должен быть рабочий стол.

Comment: Из любопытства попробовал выполнить. У меня вкладки "Taskbar", "Navigation", "Toolbars". Вероятно, это инструкция для 8.1?

Comment: @D-side: хм, странно. Вроде как для десятки.

Comment: Нашёл настройки "Пуска" в 10-ке: "Пуск", "Settings", "Personalization", "Start". Галочка "Use Start full screen". Но не знаю, как она влияет на "автооткрытие".

Comment: @D-side: вроде бы это оно.

Comment: Хотелось бы все таки пуск оставить обычным

Comment: Может есть ключ в реестре который за это отвечает?

Comment: Taskbar Properties в Windows 10 не имеют вкладки "Start Menu". Она существовала только в pre-release версиях Windows 10, а потом была убрана оттуда совсем.

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, вы выходите из Windows через меню пуск/hibernate, тогда меню пуск запоминается открытым. Они это когда-нибудь сами заметят и исправят.

Answer (score 0):

в параметрах проводника- верхний пункт:ОТКРЫТЬ ПРОВОДНИК ДЛЯ-ставим значение-этот компьютер вместо быстрый доступ( WIN 10)